# SlickGrid does not have a renderComplete event. is there an event that will fire when all rendering is done

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

While I have hacked SlickGrid to add this method [onRenderCompleted] because I can't find any built in functionality; I am searching for an answer, as I have two issues that I don't like about the hack.
1: I have messed with the base code making maintenance an issue.
2: I have this event firing on all rendering operations.

I have a 3rd party app scaffold C# MVC Serenity Web that uses declarative programming to supply a link on the grid items, mine needs to be conditional, therefore; I either need to add or remove them based on condition. Their creation is built in and makes connecting all the links and data easy, so I am  removing the links on condition. Thought it would be simple ..

I can remove the links easy enough with a little code and css trickery. My issue is when the code is running - I need to know when the grid has the slick-rows added with their respective links. RowCountChanged does not trigger at the correct time in sequence - the markup side is not yet written.
$document.ready does not work either .. and just about every other event (and I have tried a lot of them) does not fire at the proper time - (when all is loaded and rendered. - onDataLoaded does not work here either.)

I know some one mentioned using css animate object and watch for it but I have no sample code , seems that this is might be a better hack as I can add CSS ID on declarative side. And simply watch for that css object (how I don't know but would like help) .

I tried using a MutationObserver but it seems to not detect the nodes.

1: Is there a SlickGrid Event that will fire when everything is loaded and rendered?
2: If there is not a SlickGrid Event - then how can I use a css animate object and how can I watch for it to be added to the DOM?

Comment: If you use the 6pac/SlickGrid fork, we added an [onRendered](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L5824) event, it's executed as the last line in the `render()` method [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L4050) but I'm not sure if there's any async stuff then this might be too early for you and if that's the case then adding a full cycle with a simple `setTimeout(() => {} , 1)` on top of that `onRendered` event might be enough

Answer (score 1):

A few points before following up the main issue:

- I believe Serenity uses the MLiebman branch of Slickgrid. Things have moved on a lot since then, the current master is at github.com/6pac/SlickGrid, the MLiebman branch is considered dead and will have problems with later versions of JQuery
- usually, making CSS tweaks to the grid DOM elements is discouraged, because the dynamic scrolling does not work well with that technique
- note that you can define a column `formatter` which will allow you to control what appears in a cell, and it can be extended to add or remove classes from the cell/row
- note also there is a grid `enableAsyncPostRender` option for heavyweight objects that are best processed asynchronously rather than during the render operation. This works well with the scrolling, as it incorporates a mechanism for postrendering to be cancelled if a row scrolls out of the viewport before the postrender takes place. There is also a cleanup option if the rendered object requires explicit cleanup.

The best bet for instructions is to look at the wiki and examples pages.

Comment: The examples weren't working for me - from what I understand the Serenity web .implementation slick grid is tweaked - so swapping out is not to be taken lightly.
pt2 :yes in the WIKI for slickgrid. 
Looked at the asyncPostRender that is on each row (drawback?/no)  I had not figured out in serenity how to implement it.I added the onRenderComplete ,it works, scrolling not an issue:I do not like it because of the issues I mentioned.
Formatter in serenity unfortunately  only allowed me to format the data and not disable the links, I am not sure when the links are added